# How to fire inside loop async task without waiting result

Tags: c++, c++11

I need inside loop to store to file some object (serialize on every 30 seconds) and it is large object is very large so I want to just fire async task without or new thread without waiting for results but problem is that ends cope of loop and break. How to fire inside loop thread/async task ?

```
 void Person::asyncSaveCrowd(boost::shared_ptr<Crowd> crowd) {
    std::ofstream file("crowd.txt"); 
    boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(file);
    oa << crowd; 
    file.close();
 }
```

and inside loop (which is inside Crowd's member function ) I call like

```
 std::thread t(&Crowd::asyncSaveCrowd, this, this);
```

(I also tried with async call but it is same)

At the moment I have worker thread which is only waiting to read from thread safe queue and serialize but I want to avoid this worker thread and queue and for every serialization to fire async task where shared ptr is passed as parameter.

Comment: I don't quite understand your description of the problem. But if you want to start a thread, don't care about result, and want the thread to keep going after the `std::thread` object goes out of scope, you should use [thread::detach](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/detach)

Answer (score 2):

The best solution is probably to store the *thread* or *future* objects in a container, and wait for the result at the end of the loop:

```
std::vector<std::thread> threads;
for (...) {
    threads.emplace_back(&Crowd::asyncSaveCrowd, this, this);
}
for (auto&& thread : threads) {
    thread.join();
}
```

If the *async operation* is not directly created within the loop, you can either pass the *vector* or return the *thread*/*future* object.